# Having trouble with the getFeaturesAtCoordinat() method in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, jquery

Why reason when I do click in a polygon, it works and not in a point?

I have the following jQuery Code:

```
var despachosFeatures = despachosWFS.getFeaturesAtCoordinate(evt.coordinate);
var despachosJSONByWFS = format.writeFeatures(despachosFeatures);

var grifosFeatures = grifosWFS.getFeaturesAtCoordinate(evt.coordinate);
var grifosJSONByWFS = format.writeFeatures(grifosFeatures);
```

In the first and second line code, It returns a JSON with all features on the source (It's a polygon).

But, third and fourth line code, it doesn't return nothing. Why is the reason?

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}
```

I've checked the vector source "grifosWFS" and it works perfectly. Really I don't understand anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done is set a single click event for the map and checked for features at that location like below. This seems to work well.

```
map.on("singleclick", singleClickCB);

function singleClickCB(event) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function (feature) {
    return feature;
  });

  if (feature) {

    ...
    if (feature.get("features")) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the code, `getFeaturesAtCoordinate` needs a method `containsXY` on the geometry class to works. But this function is not defined for point geometry and the parent class return always `false`[see here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/68f5ff0045a9b9eb353ccf2ed85dd575620d12ab/src/ol/geom/simplegeometry.js#L88).

May be the use of `ol.source.Vector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` is more appropriate for a list of point features.

Or you can provide a buffer around the coordinate of your point and use `ol.source.Vector.forEachFeatureInExtent` (unstable)

See the [api of vector source class](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html?unstable=true)

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried with `ol.source.Vector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Does `forEachFeatureInExtent` work only with a bounding box or not?

Comment: Yes that works only with a bbox.  The `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` is visibly more efficient.